# Nginx cannot restart via Ansible

Tags: nginx, ansible

I have a task in a playbook that tries to restart nginx via a handler as per usual:

```
- name: run migrations
  command: bash -lc "some command"
  notify: restart nginx
```

The playbook however breaks on this error:

```
NOTIFIED: [deploy | restart nginx] ******************************************** 
failed: [REDACTED] => {"failed": true}
msg: failure 1 running systemctl show for 'nginx.service': Failed to get D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager.
```

The handler is standard:

```
- name: restart nginx
  service: name=nginx state=restarted enabled=yes
```

And the way that I've setup nginx is not out of the ordinary as well:

```
- name: install nginx
  apt: name=nginx state=present
  sudo: yes

- name: copy nginx.conf to the server
  template: src=nginx.conf.j2 dest=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  sudo: yes

- name: delete default virtualhost
  file: path=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default state=absent
  sudo: yes

- name: add mysite site-available
  template: src=mysite.conf.j2 dest=/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.conf
  sudo: yes

- name: link mysite site-enabled
  file: path=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite src=/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.conf state=link
  sudo: yes
```

This is on a `ubuntu-14-04-x64` VPS.

Comment: it appears your handler needs `sudo`.

Comment: `sudo` is not a supported parameter for that module

Comment: no, you need a line that says `sudo: yes` in the handler. Not `sudo=yes` on the `service` module line. If that still doesn't work, please post your updated handler and the full error message.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The handler was:

```
- name: restart nginx
  service: name=nginx state=restarted enabled=yes
```

It seems that the state and enabled flags cannot both be present. By trimming the above to the following, it worked.

```
- name: restart nginx
  service: name=nginx state=restarted
```

Why this is, and why it started breaking suddenly, I do not know.