# ansible not able to restart php5-fpm

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I have a handler trying to restart php5-fpm:

```
handlers:
    - name: restart nginx
      service: name=nginx state=restarted
    - name: restart php5fpm
      service: name=php5-fpm state=restarted
    - name: restart mysql
      service: name=mysql state=restarted
```

and a notify calling the handler:

```
- name: copy php.ini to php config folder
  template: src=php.ini.j2 dest=/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini owner=root group=root mode=0644
  changed_when: true
  notify:
    restart php5fpm
```

This fails with:

```
RUNNING HANDLER [restart php5fpm] **********************************************
fatal: [host01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type=\"method_call\", sender=\":1.313\" (uid=1002 pid=18082 comm=\"stop php5-fpm \")     interface=\"com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job\" member=\"Stop\" error name=\"(unset)\" requested_reply=\"0\" destination=\"com.ubuntu.Upstart\" (uid=0 pid=1 comm=\"/sbin/init \")\nstart: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type=\"method_call\", sender=\":1.314\" (uid=1002 pid=18086 comm=\"start php5-fpm \") interface=\"com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job\" member=\"Start\" error name=\"(unset)\" requested_reply=\"0\" destination=\"com.ubuntu.Upstart\" (uid=0 pid=1 comm=\"/sbin/init \")\n"}
```

A service restart on the VM is no problem though:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo service php5-fpm restart
php5-fpm stop/waiting
php5-fpm start/running, process 18984
```

I have already read the following:
[Nginx cannot restart via Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057992/nginx-cannot-restart-via-ansible)

And I know about the bug ansible 1.9.1 bug whit php5-fpm and ubuntu 14.04, so I already updated my ansible to

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.0.0.2
    config file = /Users/myUser/vagrant/test/ansible.cfg
    configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had exactly the same problem and here is my work around to this:

```
handlers:
 - name: restart php5fpm
   command: service php5-fpm restart
```

Hope it will help you